# Unable to import base layer onto Cartodb

Tags: carto, basemap

[image]I have been trying to import basemap (crm_hillshade) from this website http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/wiki/index.php/WMS_Service_List onto Cartodb but it keeps showing error and the basemap is unable to load.

Is anyone else having the same problem with importing basemap from this website?

Are there other websites which I can use for Cartodb maps?

Answer (score 1):

It works, you have to remove the parameters from the url so you need to put on the WMS/WMTS text box:

```
  http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/soap/web_mercator/crm_hillshade/MapServer/WMSServer
```

And CARTO will offer you the available layers that support the cartographic projection (`EPSG:3857`).

Comment: When I clicked on 'get capabilities', this is the URL I retrieved: http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/soap/web_mercator/crm_hillshade/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS. Do you mean need to remove this part '?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS'?

Comment: The map does not load. Let me show you how it looks like when I uploaded this. I have attached the screenshot with this.